# P4 Trigger, %args% parameter is empty

Tags: python, triggers, perforce

I create perforce trigger and I like to get `%args%` value.

I can't get `%args%` value.

[For more informatin go perforce doc page.](https://www.perforce.com/perforce/r14.2/manuals/p4sag/chapter.scripting.html#scripting.triggers)

This is may trigger config file.
(This we can opened for running in cmd

> p4 triggers

)

> Triggers:
>
> ```
>  change_submit change-submit //depot/... "python
>  D:\DEV\Code\tacticperforce\p4_scripts\change_submit.py %args% %change%"
> ```

**This is my** **change_submit.py**

```
import sys

import manager

args_list = sys.argv
manager.ConnectionManager.write_log(args_list)
```

**This is my log file.**

> ['D:\DEV\WFMS\Code\tacticperforce\p4_scripts\change_submit.py',
>   '91']   (91 is my %change%, but %args% is empty)

**Please help me...**

Comment: What release is your server? %args% was added in server release 2014.1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Assuming you've got a server >= 2014.1 like Bryan mentioned.)

How did you submit and what do you expect in %args% ?

For example, if I submit with:

```
p4 submit -r -dTest
```

The script will see %args% as "-r -dTest".

Since %args% can be (empty) you might want it last.   And/or enclose with quotes in your trigger definition -- %quote%%args%%quote%.

Comment: I solve this problem this way.










I just only add `pre-user-submit` trigger. :D :D



    Triggers:
     pre_submit command pre-user-submit "python D:\DEV\WFMS\Code\tacticperforce\p4_scripts/pre_submit.py %change% %args%"